# How to read refiner values from refinement panel Sharepoint oline

Tags: sharepoint-online, refinement-panel, search-results-webpart

I have to read selected refiner values from refinement panel and display it on search results web part using my custom  item_commonbody_item display template.

when I selected one refiner value ,in the url I could see the managed metadata property but not the selected value.

How can I get the selected refiner value